# Windows installation starts back up once installation is complete

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, installation, bootable-media

I recently finished building my first ever pc. While installing windows 10 onto this pc, I encountered many issues since I was using a bootable USB formatted on a Mac. I got through all these issues after nearly 2 weeks of constant trial and error, but I ended up moving my windows installation files onto my hard drive (which I’m also downloading windows onto). This was my only solution since the USB took me through most of the installation but caused errors around the last steps. Anyway, after the installation ended, my PC restarted as it should, but it brought me right back to the first windows installation page. I looked through forums to find a solution, but the most common one seemed to be to unplug the USB immediately. I use my Hard drive instead of a USB, but I can’t disconnect it since I downloaded windows onto it. Does anyone have an idea which I could try? Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10587/windows-10-get-help-with-upgrade-installation-errors

Answer (score 1):

Once Windows install has completed, the system is rebooted.

When a reboot happens, the computer will try to boot in certain order. It sounds like in your case, the external drive is preferred. This is not ideal, as it presents the problem you have discovered. It better to default to the internal drive.

The solution to the problem is either to change the boot order in the BIOS, or as others said to remove the external drive immediately upon being notified that computer is restarting.